# AVAudioPlayer currentTime lag issue

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, nstimeinterval

When I change the `currentTime` of `AVAudioPlayer` after pausing the player, it gives a lag (some time in positive and some time in negative).

```
[self.bookAudioPlayer pause];
[self.bookAudioPlayer setCurrentTime:[currentPage.audioStartTime doubleValue]];
[self.bookAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

When I print the `currentTime` and `audioStartTime` it prints values with slight difference. For example,

> audioStartTime : 2.203665, currentTime : 2.194286
>
> audioStartTime : 137.521347, currentTime : 137.508571

I have tried to fix it using the following code but results stay the same.

```
- (void)fixSetCurentTime:(NSTimeInterval)newTime {
    self.currentTime = newTime;
    
    if (self.currentTime != newTime) {
        [self prepareToPlay];
        self.currentTime = newTime;
    }
}
```

Has anyone experienced this issue? Any pointers for a possible fix?

Comment: you should use AVPlayer instead of AVAudioPlayer if you can, even for audio. my experience, it works better

Answer (score 4):

Note that the MP3 audio frames are about 26 milliseconds long. So, block-based audio compression formats are only (re)startable on time-quantized block boundaries... And the nearest block start might be earlier (or later) in time.

Credit: Apple Developer Forum User ([Reference](https://devforums.apple.com/message/964234))